# Opening a Video Link and then returning to the home page once closed

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

I have the following mobile site in which you click on Watch Live Races and it opens up Just fine, but after clicking done on the video, it stays on that page and doesn't return to the Home page.

N.B. It works on Safari IOS 7 but not on Safari IOS 8.

m.racingnsw.com.au

How can I redirect it after you click done.?
this is the code used

```js
window.location.assign("http://kitdigitaioslive-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/219670/skyr_ios_unblocked/skyrnsw.m3u8", "_self");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried the following without any success  window.location.assign(url);
window.location = url;
window.location.href = url;

Comment: have You tried to alert(url) before redirecting? I mean maybe there is another problem before it :)

Comment: Can you make 'done' a link?

Comment: Hi num8er,I am not so good coding, how exactly would I put the alert(url)..?